# Open word on local computer - Office URI Schemes special characters

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, office365, uri

I want to open word-documents by clicking on a link in my solution. The link below shows how it is structured in ofe for office. This solution is really nice because it works in every browser but i have problems with special characters.

ms-word:ofe|u|file://our.local/Testing ÅÄÖ.DOCX

I Have tried different approaches to solve this problem but its not working when åäö is present in the path. EncodeURI on the path does not help for instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes does not describe anything out of the ordinary and only follow URI spec.

Documents without special characters works great but i can not figure out how special characters should be encoded to make it work.

[image: Wrong URI]

If i take the file:\... part and past it into any browser it is working but not with the ofe prefix. So it should be some problem with encoding due to it is working fine without any special characters.

Running in cmd is also working:

[image: Cmd]

So in this case i guess the browser is encoding the characters before sending to protocolhandler ??

Comment: Any luck on your side so far?

Comment: @ornic It has been approved by Microsoft as a bug and sent to the development team but i have not received any updated yet. I will post an update here when i have received any feedback from my ticket att Microsoft.

Comment: It has been fixed in the following O365 version: 16.0.11901.20070 @ornic and it may take up to 3-4 months for MSI products..

Comment: We're got it working on our corporate 365 office via Monthly channel :)

Comment: @ornic Could you supply a working jsfiddle pointing to c:\temp\teståäö.docx ? For me it still does not work! I wonder if it could be an encoding issue ..

Comment: They corrected this error only from console, as I was told. From browser it is still there. :(

Comment: Does anyone have a solution? I am still facing this issue

Comment: @NetProvoke Would you still have a link to that issue?

Comment: @Akxe Sorry but I dont have it. I work as a consultant and this issue was something a previous customer had issues with years ago. I ended up doing a solution to this on my own..